# An intent redirects me to a wrong activity

Tags: java, android, authentication, button

Unfortunately the button I tried to design doesn't work. I have three activities: Login, Register and MainActivity (which is a blank activity) and on the Login activity I have this register button ("button") that I want to redirect to Register activity but it redirects me to a blank page when I run the app. What should I do?

```
package com.example.scooterzapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
EditText etEmail,etParola,etNume,etPrenume,etUsername,etVarsta,etNumarDeTelefon;
Button bReg;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    etNume =  findViewById(R.id.etNume);
    etPrenume =  findViewById(R.id.etPrenume);
    etUsername =  findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etParola =  findViewById(R.id.etParola);
    etEmail =  findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etNumarDeTelefon =  findViewById(R.id.etNumarDeTelefon);
    etVarsta =  findViewById(R.id.etVarsta);
    bReg= findViewById(R.id.bReg);
    fAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if(fAuth.getCurrentUser()!= null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    bReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String Parola = etParola.getText().toString().trim();


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {
                etEmail.setError("Campul trebuie completat.");
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Parola)) {
                etParola.setError("Campul trebuie completat.");
                return;
            }
            if (Parola.length() < 6) {
                etParola.setError("Parola trebuie sa fie formata din cel putin 6 caractere");
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Parola).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "V-ati inregistrat cu succes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Inregistrare esuata.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: I don't see an issue in the code you posted. There could be an issue in `Register.java` or `register.xml`, if you are looking for further help, please copy the code of these files into your post.

Comment: i've posted the code below

Comment: You can edit your first post and add it there. Please include the whole `activity_register` file, not just the views.

Comment: i cannot put both parts  of the code in this question , sry , i ve posted another answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Greet from Nice ;) try below code

```
button.setOnClickListener  (new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public   void   onClick(View v) {
           startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Register.class));
       }
   });
```